# Glwidget in qt issue with coordinates

Tags: macos, qt, opengl, coordinates, qglwidget

I am running qt 4.7 on Mac OS X and the coordinates are being drawn wrong for glwidget. I've tried it on a Fedora box and it works fine. Does anyone know if there's a bug in glwidget for mac? or how I can fix it?

Comment: Please post some source code. Preferrably a fully working, minimal example that exhibits the described behaviour.

Comment: Some code will help people understand and reproduce your issue. You can check for known Qt bugs here: http://bugreports.qt.nokia.com/secure/IssueNavigator.jspa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution: I had original installed only the libs, but when I installed the framework with qtcreator it worked!!!